# innerHTML javascript changing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying  to make this code work, I want the `innerHTML` to be changed but It's instantly changing and gets back to its initial state . Any help ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function click_me(){ 
                alert('fdsfs');
                var tweety=document.getElementById('text_this').innerHTML;
                alert(tweety);
                var text_area="<input type=text value='"+tweety+"'>";
                alert(text_area);
                document.getElementById('text_this').innerHTML=text_area; 
             }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form name="form1">
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="text_this">123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="click_me();">Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `form` is getting submitted. Add a `return false;` to your button `onclick` event.

```
<button onclick="click_me(); return false;">Edit</button>
```

Or, make the button `type='button'` (This is the **better** option)

```
<button onclick="click_me();" type='button'>Edit</button>
```

The reason is because the button `type` is `submit` by default if a `type` is **not specified**.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button),

> submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the
>   default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is
>   dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function click_me(){ 
      alert('fdsfs');
      var tweety=document.getElementById('text_this').innerHTML;
      alert(tweety);
      var text_area="<input type=text value='"+tweety+"'>";
      alert(text_area);
      document.getElementById('text_this').innerHTML=text_area; 
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form1">
      <table border=1>
        <tr>
          <td><div id="text_this">123</div></td>
          <td><button onclick="click_me();return false;">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

added a return false statement to the onclick event. without it, the form gets submitted and the page reloads

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R7gWy/1/)

Comment: I don't believe a `<button>` does submit the page.

Comment: Buttons' actions are browser-specific. Some do submit forms: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp).

It's better to use <input> tags in that case.

Comment: @Rogue: Yes, default seems to be submit. I have posted the MDN link and content in my answer above.

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso http://codepen.io/11684/pen/mEHvI On my end, the button in your fiddle is unclickable.

Comment: exactly, for a form to be submitted you need a form

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry. That's why I doubted it was form submission in the first place.

Comment: @11684: Strange, but in codepen even if I add a form it is not getting submitted but in jsFiddle it does. There must be some difference between those two. But I still think MDN wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: @11684—while MDN isn't wrong about that, it's just a community Wiki and is wrong and in need of update about some things.